# ACF get image from product term

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to display a brand logo on my product pages. I use Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to insert the image on the taxonomy "Brand".

https://snipboard.io/JcYvM4.jpg

I have tried the code below, and tried to do as on the page here, but it doens't work...

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

*The image return format is "Array".

```
function action_woocommerce_before_variations_form(  ) { 

    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
    $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;  
    
    $image = get_field('brand_logo', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    echo '<img src="'.$image['url'].'" />';
    
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_variations_form', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Maybe you call an hook that doesn't exist on your theme. You can try with woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form hook instead of woocommerce_before_variations_form

Comment: Hi Zecka
Thank you for your comment.
If I just echo "Test", the text will appear nicely on the product page.

Comment: And if you type echo var_dump($image); What do you have ?

Comment: The result of this is "NULL".

Comment: So debug other variable: $taxonomy and $term_id

Comment: If I var_dump() them all, I get this output: NULL string(0) "" string(0) ""

Comment: Because get_queried_object() return a product in product page, not a brand. So you have to find the brand id with your product id and then get the image of the brand

Comment: do you find a solution or still need help ?

Comment: Hey. So far I have not found a solution. I can see what you mean, so just try me out. If I find a solution, then I write. :-)

Comment: I add answer, is it working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<?php
$category_icon = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$category-logo = wp_get_attachment_url( $category_icon );
?>
```

Comment: Hi
Thank you for your comment. It is not the category image I want to display. I have a product property called "Brands". Under each brand I have made such that I can add a logo with ACF. It's this picture I can not get.

Answer (score 0):

The woocommerce_before_variations_form is call on product page.

So if when you call `get_queried_object()` WordPress will return Product Object, not brand term.

So

1. Get brand(s) with your product id with [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function
2. Iterate on your brands and get image with [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function
3. (optional) get brand link
4. Display your image

```php
<?php 

function prefix_add_brand_before_variations_form() {
    // First get brand(s) with your product id. 
    $brands = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'brand');
    
    // get_the_terms return false or an array, so 
    if(!$brands) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($brands as $brand) {
        $image = get_field('brand_logo', $brand);
        $brand_url = get_term_link($brand);
        if (is_array($image)) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $brand_url ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
            </a>
        <?php
        endif;
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'prefix_add_brand_before_variations_form', 10, 0);
```